# Spring and Factorymethod

Tags: java, spring-boot, polymorphism

I would like to instantiate a class in a factory method and execute the respective implementation of the method defined in the interface.
My problem is that I don't want to create the dependencies of such a class (they are nested) myself, but rather that Spring injects them into this class.

My code is:

```
public Interface BasicProcess {
     Message createProcess()
}


@RequiredArgsConstructor
public Class WorkProcess implements BasicProcess {
 
   private final HelperService;
   
   @Override
   Message createProcess(){
      //do some logik
   }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public Class EatProcess implements BasicProcess {

   private FoodService;

   @Override
   Message createProcess(){
      //do some other logik
   }
}
```

and now I decide, which "Bean" i am instantiating:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Factory(){

     
     private final HelperService helperService;

     
     private final FoodService foodService;

     public BasicProcess factoryMethod(String param){

         if(param=="Work"){
             return new WorkProcess(helperService)
         } else if (param == "Food") {

              return new EatProcess(foodService)
         }
     
     }
    }
```

and now i'am calling particular implementation:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
class SomeClass{

   private final Factory factory;

   public void startProcess(){
        BasicProcess processfactory.factoryMethod("Food");
        processfactory.createProcess(); //calling EatProcess implementation
   }

}
```

Is there some better Solutions to call dynamicly "createProcess"?
I dont like to say "new WorkProcess(....)"

Comment: Don't use `param=="Work"`, use `param.equals("Work")` (or the null-tolerating `"Work".equals(param)`) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the necessary dependencies into the constructor of `SomeClass`, and then use those dependencies to create instances of the `BasicProcess` implementations.

Working code :

```
public interface BasicProcess {
    Message createProcess();
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WorkProcess implements BasicProcess {

    private final HelperService helperService;

    @Override
    public Message createProcess() {
        // other codes
        return new Message("WorkProcess executed");
    }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EatProcess implements BasicProcess {

    private final FoodService foodService;

    @Override
    public Message createProcess() {
        // other logic
        return new Message("EatProcess executed");
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Factory {

    private final HelperService helperService;
    private final FoodService foodService;

    public BasicProcess factoryMethod(String param) {
        if ("Work".equals(param)) {
            return new WorkProcess(helperService);
        } else if ("Food".equals(param)) {
            return new EatProcess(foodService);
        }
        return null; 
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeClass {

    private final Factory factory;

    public void startProcess() {
        BasicProcess process = factory.factoryMethod("Food");
        if (process != null) {
            process.createProcess(); // calling EatProcess implementation
        } else {
            // Handle invalid param 
        }
    }
}
```

Here your dependencies `HelperService` and `FoodService` are injected into the constructors of `WorkProcess` and `EatProcess`.  factory method in the Factory class is responsible for creating instances of BasicProcess implementations based on parameter. The SomeClass component then uses the factory to obtain an instance and call the createProcess method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a beautiful way to work with Spring.

1. Add a method `param` in BasicProcess.

```java
public interface BasicProcess {
    Message createProcess();

    String param();
}
```

2. Define your implements with @Component.

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WorkProcess implements BasicProcess {

    // Spring will inject bean into this field
    private final HelperService;

    @Override
    public Message createProcess() {
        //do some logic
    }

    @Override
    public String param() {
        return "Work";
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EatProcess implements BasicProcess {

    private FoodService;

    @Override
    public Message createProcess() {
        //do some other logic
    }

    @Override
    public String param() {
        return "Food";
    }
}
```

3. Inject all BasicProcess into your factory.

```
@Service
public class Factory implements InitializingBean {

    // Spring will inject all bean which implements BasicProcess into this field.
    @Autowired
    private List<BasicProcess> basicProcessList;

    private final Map<String, BasicProcess> basicProcessMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        if (Objects.nonNull(basicProcessList)) {
            basicProcessList.forEach(
                    process -> basicProcessMap.put(process.param(), process)
            );
            basicProcessList = null; // help gc
        }
    }

    public BasicProcess factoryMethod(String param) {
        return basicProcessMap.get(param);
    }
}
```